# Confused in selecting file format to serve as a template

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I'm serving docx file as a template to user but the docx2html module is not working well, i just want to know that which file format is served by other resume builder apps like canva and zety. Or any other suggestions may be helpful.

I want to serve a template to the user so that he/she enters his details in it and download it in pdf format

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.